# How to wait for FluentWebElement?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, fluentlenium

I have the page object as below:

```
@FindBy (className = "all-time-menu-icon")
private FluentWebElement enrichmentOptions;

/**
 * @return  FluentWebElement for Enrichment options
 */
public FluentWebElement getEnrichmentOptions() {
    return enrichmentOptions;
}
```

Now I want to call the above FluentWebElement getEnrichmentOptions() from the testcase with some waiting expected condition?

Please help with respect to the above scenario. 
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

use wait like below:

```
await().atMost(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).until("ur locator -- id or classname").withText("myText").hasSize(3);
```

or

```
await().atMost(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).until("ur locator").withText("myText").hasText("TextValue");
```

or

```
await().atMost(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).until("ur locator").withText("myText").isPresent();
```

you can also use

```
isNotPresent(), hasId("myId"), hasName("myName"), containsText("myName"),areDisplayed(), areEnabled().
```

Check the docs as well https://fluentlenium.com/

Comment: Instead of using "ur locator" I want to use the getEnrichmentOptions() method (returning the fluentwebelement. Any help about this?

Comment: u can send the instance of elements there also like this:     await().atMost(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).until(getEnrichmentOptions()).withText("myText").hasSize(3);

Comment: the parameter for 'until' is not taking the fluentwebelement!! It asks for predicate <Fluent>. Actually I am facing the issue with passing the fluentwebelement the until is not accepting the FluentWebElement.

Comment: have u import this:: import com.google.common.base.Predicate;

Comment: just import this and this will be ok